# Show a link to a path in a message form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink

I have a desktop application in C# .In this I have a form in which I show different messages .
I have one message who  say : "The output  file was generated in : C:\Work\result.txt".
How can I show this path to the file as a link and when the form with this message is shown to see the path as a link and when the user click the link to open the specified path/file?

I tried :

```
The output  file was generated in : <a href=/" C:\Work\result.txt/">C:\Work\result.txt</a>
```

But doesn't work.

Thanks !

Comment: May LinkLabel will help

Comment: @wonko79 of course, but that `LinkLabel` should be added to a standard Form, not the MessageBox window.

Comment: I think you can't have such a `MessageBox` in .NET, the solution is to customize your own MessageBox or use a third-party one.

Comment: How can I use a Linklabel if I have messages like :My first file is in location path1 ,my second file is in location path2,my third file is in location path3...My messages can vary.My form has a label where i show the message and an icon (succes or error message)+ ok button

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. But it will be very easy to build a MessageBox-like form yourself. You can use the LinkLabel control to add hyperlinks.

Comment: MessageBox.Show("test message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information,
             MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, "http://google.com", "Keyword"); But dont place it in the Window Load

Answer (score 2):

You can have an event for on-onclick, and then you can open file using the below code.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Work\result.txt"); //or like
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Work\result.docx");
```

Here, the default program must be there for the file. Then only shell will run associated program reading it from the registry, like usual double click does in explorer.

Comment: You misunderstood the OP's question, he doesn't want to know how to open the file which is associated with a link. He wants to display the link in a `MessageBox`. The standard `MessageBox` can't work that way, and the solution is try using a third-party UI library which supports some kind of MessageBox with rich features allowing user to format and define how the text looks.

Comment: OP: "How can I show this path to the file as a link and when the form with this message is shown to see the path as a link and when the user click the link to open the specified path/file" - use [LinkLabel](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/06/an-overview-of-link-label-in-c/) contrl, on `LinkClick` event, use the above code to open the file.. @KingKong: not `MessageBox`, on `Form` with this `Message`. Here, `LinkLabel` can be used

Comment: I made a form with a label and a picture in what i show the message.My messages vary and in one message I can have one or three paths.And that 's the reason that I think i can't use linklabel

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox.Show() method takes the caption, text, icon, buttons and default button of the dialog.However there's nothing mentioned in the .NET Framework documentation that says anything about adding links to a MessageBox

However, you can do the effect you want by creating a new class inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Form and add a button (or more if you like), an icon, a label and a LinkButton. Then  use the ShowDialog() Method of the Form class to display the message box in modal form. You may also create a class called MyErrorBox (static class in C# 2 or just sealed in C# 1) that contains only one static method called Show() which creates a form, adds the needed controls and displays the form in modal mode. A demonstration of the last method is shown below. Then you can use this class whenever you want and wherever you please!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MessageBoxes{
public sealed class MyErrorBox{

private MyErrorBox(){}
private static Form frm;
private static string detailsStore;
private static TextBox txt;

public static DialogResult Show(string caption, string text, string details, Icon icon){

    frm = new Form(); frm.Size = new Size(510, 195);
    frm.Text = caption; frm.ShowInTaskbar = false; frm.ControlBox = false;
    frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    PictureBox icon1 = new PictureBox(); icon1.Location = new Point(8,16);
    icon1.Size = new Size(icon.Width, icon.Height);
    icon1.Image = icon.ToBitmap();
    frm.Controls.Add(icon1);
    Label lbl = new Label(); lbl.Text = text; lbl.Location = new Point(88,8);
    lbl.Size = new Size(400,88); frm.Controls.Add(lbl);
    LinkLabel btn1 = new LinkLabel(); btn1.Text = "View Details";
    btn1.Size = new Size(72,23); btn1.Location = new Point(416,96);
    btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click); frm.Controls.Add(btn1);
    //Ofcourse you can add more buttons than just the ok with more DialogResults
    Button btn2 = new Button(); btn2.Text = "&Ok";
    btn2.Size = new Size(72,23); btn2.Location = new Point(224,130);
    btn2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom; frm.Controls.Add(btn2);
    frm.AcceptButton = btn2; btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn2_Click);
    btn2.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; detailsStore = details;
    return frm.ShowDialog();

 }

private static void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    frm.Size = new Size(510,320);
    txt = new TextBox(); txt.Multiline = true;
    txt.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both; txt.Text = detailsStore;
    txt.Size = new Size(488,128); txt.Location = new Point(8,120);
    txt.ReadOnly = true; frm.Controls.Add(txt);
    LinkLabel lnk = (LinkLabel)(sender); lnk.Text = "Hide Details";
    lnk.Click -= new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
    lnk.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_ReClick);

}

private static void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    frm.Close();

}

private static void btn1_ReClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    frm.Controls.Remove(txt); frm.Size = new Size(510, 195);
    LinkLabel lnk = (LinkLabel)(sender); lnk.Text = "View Details";
    lnk.Click -= new EventHandler(btn1_ReClick);
    lnk.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);

   }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard MessageBox functionality that'll be able to do this via link label. What I suggest is you use the Yes/No Messagebox buttons and from the option selected you then apply an event

Something like this:

```
if (MessageBox.Show(
    "The file is saved at the following link: link here", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk
) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\TestLocation\SavedFiles");
}
```